# AttributeError: partially initialized module 'unittest' has no attribute 'TestCase' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, python-unittest

```
import unittest

class TestSum(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_sum(self):
        self.assertEqual(sum([1, 2, 3]), 6, "Should be 6")

    def test_sum_tuple(self):
        self.assertEqual(sum((1, 2, 2)), 6, "Should be 6")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Unit test that worked before is not working now. Is there a point you missed?

Comment: Did you create your own `unittest` file? you shouldn't. If you decide to do it anyway don't call `TestSum` from it.

Comment: I called TestCase from the standard unittest library. I got from these python documentations [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html)

Comment: My mistake wrong filename

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a `py-file` named `unittest` in the current directory? 
It may cause `AttributeError`. Check your filename.